# Trying to modify existing file with spreadsheet gem, Excel complains of 'missing data'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spreadsheet

I'm trying to write a Rails app to automate several manual processes for a business. They had a ton of different Excel spreadsheets that they would manually enter data into and copy data between.  I've has success using the 'spreadsheet' gem to read data from some of their existing reports (so they can populate the app) and also generate Excel reports from data contained in the app (so they have a format they are comfortable with).

This report is causing a lot of headaches, though. It has 2 sheets - the first is an interactive pivot table and the second is the raw data that feeds the report.

I have no idea how I could build this from scratch using the spreadsheet gem (it depends on VB modules and pivot table reports embedded in the spreadsheet), so I thought I would use the existing report as a template and just write new data onto the second sheet.

The first hurdle I ran into was that the file is in `UTF-16LE` but spreadsheet kept trying to write it as `UTF-8`. I finally got that cleared up, and now the file is generated, but when I open it in Excel, I get tons of error messages:

```
Excel found unreadable content in 'output.xls'. 
Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? Yes No
File error: data may have been lost.
```

then Excel attempts to `Open and Repair` the file... then I get:

```
Microsoft Visual Basic: File Not Found 
File error: data may have been lost.
```

...again.  Then the report comes up - the second page has all the written data, but the first page doesn't work - `Repairs` to the file states:

```
Lost Visual Basic project. 
PivotTable report 'PivotTable1' on [...]PivotSheet was discarded due to integrity problems.
```

Any idea why it's corrupting/removing the VB module in the template spreadsheet?

Comment: I've never used the spreadsheet gem,  but I do manually create csv's without problem.  I don't have to do anything relating to character encoding,  the only thing I remember was that if I opened the output csv like so:  out = File.open('file.csv','w'),  it wouldn't work,  but File.open('file.csv','w+') does work.  The '+' is apparently ignored on Unix,  but on Windows,  it's required to get the file opened in binary mode.  This probably won't help you much, because you use a GEM to do the low level stuff.  I'm guessing you are testing on Windows?

Comment: @RadBrad - I am testing on Windows, but I'm not actually writing the output to a file - I'm writing to StringIO and then returning the output back directly from the controller.